# JQuery UI - accordion - display a div element over the aacordion

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion that displays items I have entered values from some input items - e.g., if I select a date, the accordion displays the selected date etc.

sample screen - top portion is the accordion with selected values and the bottom portion is where I enter the values

---

```
Date: Sep 20 2013 | Customer: MLJJ
```

---

Date : ***_*__*_*__**
Customer : **__*_*__*_*__*_***

I have a div that pops up when a user clicks on the input field for date. I wanted to do the same for the read-only text in the accordion. But the top portion of my date slider is hidden by the accordion. I have tried setting the z-index to some very high values, but to no avail. Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance.

**Code Snippets**

```
    function positionMe(myTextBox) {
    var mybox = myTextBox;
    $("#popup").show();
    $( "#popup" ).position({
                               of: $( mybox ),
                               my: "left top",
                               at: "left bottom"
                           });
}
```

popup is a div

```
   <div id="popup">
    <div class="input">

        <div>
            <input type="text" id="timeslice" size="5" />

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself -

I appended the popup div to the accordion element and then positioned it. That seems to show the popup.

```
   $("div#top-criteria").append($("div#popup"));
    positionRight('div#top-criteria');
```

Thanks

I apologize if the question was a bit vague.